# No internet connection with an Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 adapter

Tags: ethernet, atheros

I have Ubuntu on my netbook. It wont connect to the internet, I did a system check and I have a Attansic Technology corp. Atheros AR8121/AR8113/AR 8114 PCI-E, ethernet controller (revb0).

I'm not sure how to get it to connect can someone please help me out?